# Case sensitivity (or StringComparison) of network shares?

Tags: .net, naming, case-sensitive, unc, network-share

**What is the case sensitivity of names of [network shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_resource#Naming_convention_and_mapping)?**

Example from UNC path: (the `sharename` component only)

```
\\hostname\sharename\directoryname1\directorynameN\filename.ext
```

- Can `sharename` be case-sensitive on some systems?
- Is the best [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) for share names `OrdinalIgnoreCase`/`Ordinal`?
  (I am asking because ordinal comparisons are not automatically everywhere – for example NetBIOS server names [seem to use `CurrentCulture` comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724220(v=vs.85).aspx) – well... not exactly, but closest to it.)

I was unable to find good resource which discusses case sensitivity and allowed characters for names of network shares.